# How to delay image load with data URI?

Tags: javascript, performance, image, loading, data-uri

I am using data URI to load images one page and I put `script` at the end of my HTML. Unlike use normal url for image `src`, the data will be directly loaded in the HTTP request for the html page.

Thus, the `script` will be loaded very late at the end of the page as I have hundreds of image data loaded through this way.

I want to load the script either earlier or asynchronous with the load of imate, is there a way to delay the load of image `data`?

```
<div>
  <img src="data:image/png; base64, .........." alt="">
  <img src="data:image/png; base64, .........." alt="">
  <img src="data:image/png; base64, .........." alt="">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: you could just hide the div or the images and once the script loads display them, or use visibility to keep the layout intact

Comment: The image could be hidden but it still will be **loaded**, it doesn't solve the problem of delaying loading scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is fairly straightforward.  If you don't want the images loaded synchronously with the page load, then don't use inline image data URIs.  You are getting the behavior that you have coded your web page for.

Remote image URLs (non-data URIs) load asychronously and you can run scripts while they are loading.

Or, you could put all the data URIs into a big string array in your page and then use javascript to construct the image objects from the data URIs after you've done your other javascript.

Comment: The last one - put date URIs into a big string array - could be a work around here although use JS to carry the data is not elegant and site will jS turned off won't receive the image at all.

Comment: You asked what the options are, we're just explaining them to you.  It's up to you to pick the option that makes the most sense for your situation.  Using a zillion data URIs doesn't make much sense to me at all.  Web browsers weren't designed to handle that problem well.  They were designed to handle the problem of a lot of regular image URLs.

Comment: Sure.It's ugly.  Under the constrains that data URI will be used, there seems to be no perfect solution to load the following scripts asynchronous. I will abort the data URI and consider other solutions to either speed up image load and enable asynchronous scripts load.